# I can not start my computer after instaling ubuntu

Tags: reboot

After i succesfully instal ubuntu 14 and reboot i can not start anything niether Ubuntu or windows.
Message which apear is 
Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press any key.

Can you help me what to do ?

Comment: You have not selected a proper boot device in your BIOS/UEFI. Make sure the right device is enabled.

Comment: Can you send me how it schould looks like to start my comp normaly ?

Comment: Select your HDD/SSD if you have multiple, select the harddrive you selected for bootloader installation during the setup.

Answer (score 0):

Check your first boot device in BIOS, If pendrive or other useb media in firstboot device, the insert boot media option will appear